# R-check the first and last record per day per id/ loop

Tags: r, loops, optimization, logic

How can I find out the FIRST and LAST record of a day within same ID ?

SAMPLE DATA:

```
sample<- data.frame(
id=c("A","A","A","A","A","C","C","C","D","D","E","E"),
location=c("US","US","US","US","SINGAPORE","CHINA","CHINA","JAPAN","JAPAN","JAPAN","SINGAPORE","SINGAPORE"),
Date =c("03/03/2013","03/03/2013","04/03/2013","04/03/2013","05/03/2013","03/03/2013","04/03/2013","04/03/2013","05/03/2013","06/03/2013","05/03/2013","05/03/2013")

)
```

Currently I tried by using Find out the First and last record.
but it seems like dosen't works well.

Tried Codes:

```
sample$FIRST <- !duplicated(sample$id)
sample$LAST<-FALSE
sample$LAST <- c(sample$id[-nrow(sample)]==sample$id[-1],TRUE)
```

how can I implement the code to achieve my expected outcome?

Expected outcome:

```
sample<- data.frame(
id=c("A","A","A","A","A","C","C","c","D","D","E","E"),
Date=c("03/03/2013","03/03/2013","04/03/2013","04/03/2013","05/03/2013","03/03/2013","04/03/2013","04/03/2013","05/03/2013","06/03/2013","05/03/2013","05/03/2013"),
FIRST =c("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"),
LAST =c("FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE")
)
```

Thanks in advance... 
note : Due to data is in huge volume optimization is need to be consider...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it with dplyr:

```
sample$Date <- as.Date(sample$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")     #convert to dates

require(dplyr)

sample <- sample %.%                       #take the data.frame `sample` and store result of the following operation in `sample`. As I mentioned in the comment, the %.% chains several operations together.
  group_by(id, Date) %.%                   #now we make groups of the data for each combination of id and Date 
  mutate(count = 1:n(),                    #mutate adds new columns to sample. `count` counts the number of rows per group of id Date combination 
    FIRST = count == 1,                    #the column FIRST is TRUE if column count == 1
    LAST = count == max(count))            #the column LAST is TRUE if column count == maximum count per group, which is the last row

sample$count <- NULL                     #since you dont need the count column, you can remove it later on
```

The output is:

```
#   id  location       Date FIRST  LAST
#1   A        US 2013-03-03  TRUE FALSE 
#2   A        US 2013-03-03 FALSE  TRUE
#3   A        US 2013-03-04  TRUE FALSE
#4   A        US 2013-03-04 FALSE  TRUE
#5   A SINGAPORE 2013-03-05  TRUE  TRUE
#6   C     CHINA 2013-03-03  TRUE  TRUE
#7   C     CHINA 2013-03-04  TRUE FALSE
#8   C     JAPAN 2013-03-04 FALSE  TRUE       <<-- this line had a lower case "c" as id in the input, I corrected it to capital C, otherwise it would produce a separate id
#9   D     JAPAN 2013-03-05  TRUE  TRUE
#10  D     JAPAN 2013-03-06  TRUE  TRUE
#11  E SINGAPORE 2013-03-05  TRUE FALSE
#12  E SINGAPORE 2013-03-05 FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: hi, @beginneR what function you use for %.% ? [Error: could not find function "%.%"]  and can you explain how does these code works? thanks !

Comment: @momoni that is part of the package `dplyr`. You have to install the package and load it into your library. The `%.%` operator chains several operations together. For an introduction to the package, see [Introduction to dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

Comment: opps , sorry @beginneR my i change the name of the outcome dataframe, it should be only 1 dataset

Comment: @momoni sure, that is no problem. I will edit my answer and include some comments

Comment: when I want to install the package it show me this [ package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)] is it my R version is outdated ?

Comment: @momoni there is a newer version of R (3.1.0) which you would need to install to use dplyr. See for example [this post](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/) how to update R

Comment: then how can I change all the value into true false instead of numbers? as I need the true false values to use it in the next function. thanks

Comment: The values in FIRST and LAST are in fact TRUE / FALSE values in my answer

Comment: Certainly, but maybe someone else can suggest another approach. If you run `sessionInfo()` what does it say about the R version you are running?

Comment: I have updated the R but it cannot install dplyr still. Are there any alternative ways ? and I dont understand your explanation on  [The values in FIRST and LAST are in fact TRUE / FALSE values in my answer] as At the sample datasets there are no TRUE and FALSE values... I want to add FIST column and LAST column filled with true or false value to find out first and last record. thanks for helping .

Comment: did you have a look at the output i added to my answer? you can see there that the columns FIRST and LAST are true/false. by the way, you have a typo in your ids. One of the "c" is lower case while the rest is upper case. I corrected that in my answer

Comment: thanks for further explanation I will try to solved the installation problems. Thanks

Comment: hi, sorry am I allow to ask one more question? After I run the codes the results appeared under Values category  in the workspace how can I change it back to Data category ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Converting to date format is usually done with `as.Date(..., format="...")` but its hard to tell without seeing the data.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.. in R studio there is workspace at the right hand side.. under the workspace there are 3 category : Data ,Values , Functions. However after running the code the results appear at Values [sample  grouped_df[12]]. How can I put this sample results back to the Data category? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding `%.% as.data.frame()` right after `LAST = count == max(count))`. Does that change anything? Anyway, I dont see a reason to care much about those categories. If it doesnt work, you might be better off asking a separate question